# Breadcrumbs Subcategory Link is Missing

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, breadcrumbs

I dont use plugin for Breadcrumbs. This is ok for me. I checked category parents. Everything is ok. But something wrong

I have a category and sub categories.

Like this :

BCD - Category

xyz - 
Sub-Category

Hello - 
Post Title.

**Code output :**

Home Page > BCD > Hello    (Where is the sub-category ?)

Sub category is missing.

But if Sub-Category name start with A character  For example abc

**Code output:**

Home Page > BCD > abc > Hello

--

```
// Breadcrumb
function breadcrumb() {
     $delimiter = '';
  $name = 'Home'; //text for the 'Home' link
  $currentBefore = '<span class="current">';
  $currentAfter = '</span>';
    echo 'You are here:';

    global $post;
    $home = get_bloginfo('url');

    if(is_home() && get_query_var('paged') == 0) 
        echo '<span class="home">' . $name . '</span>';
    else
        echo '<a class="home" href="' . $home . '">' . $name . '</a> '. $delimiter . ' ';

    if ( is_category() ) {
      global $wp_query;
      $cat_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
      $thisCat = $cat_obj->term_id;
      $thisCat = get_category($thisCat);
      $parentCat = get_category($thisCat->parent);
      if ($thisCat->parent != 0) echo(get_category_parents($parentCat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' '));
      echo $currentBefore;
      single_cat_title();
      echo $currentAfter;

    } elseif ( is_day() ) {
      echo '<a href="' . get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')) . '">' . get_the_time('Y') . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
      echo '<a href="' . get_month_link(get_the_time('Y'),get_the_time('m')) . '">' . get_the_time('F') . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
      echo $currentBefore . get_the_time('d') . $currentAfter;

    } elseif ( is_month() ) {
      echo '<a href="' . get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')) . '">' . get_the_time('Y') . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
      echo $currentBefore . get_the_time('F') . $currentAfter;

    } elseif ( is_year() ) {
      echo $currentBefore . get_the_time('Y') . $currentAfter;

    } elseif ( is_single() ) {
      $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0];
      echo get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
      echo $currentBefore;
      the_title();
      echo $currentAfter;

    } elseif ( is_page() && !$post->post_parent ) {
      echo $currentBefore;
      the_title();
      echo $currentAfter;

    } elseif ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {
      $parent_id  = $post->post_parent;
      $breadcrumbs = array();
      while ($parent_id) {
        $page = get_page($parent_id);
        $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . get_the_title($page->ID) . '</a>';
        $parent_id  = $page->post_parent;
      }
      $breadcrumbs = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
      foreach ($breadcrumbs as $crumb) echo $crumb . ' ' . $delimiter . ' ';
      echo $currentBefore;
      the_title();
      echo $currentAfter;

    } elseif ( is_search() ) {
      echo $currentBefore . 'Search for ' . get_search_query() . $currentAfter;

    } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
      echo $currentBefore;
      single_tag_title();
      echo $currentAfter;

    } elseif ( is_author() ) {
       global $author;
      $userdata = get_userdata($author);
      echo $currentBefore. $userdata->display_name . $currentAfter;

    } elseif ( is_404() ) {
      echo $currentBefore . 'Error 404' . $currentAfter;
    }

    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
      if ( is_category() || is_day() || is_month() || is_year() || is_search() || is_tag() || is_author() ) echo ' (';
      echo $currentBefore . __('Page') . ' ' . get_query_var('paged') . $currentAfter;
      if ( is_category() || is_day() || is_month() || is_year() || is_search() || is_tag() || is_author() ) echo ')';
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well so here is the code I modified to fix this issue...

```
  function wordpress_breadcrumbs() {

     $delimiter = '';
     $name = 'Home'; //text for the 'Home' link
     $currentBefore = '<li>';
     $currentAfter = '</li>';

  if ( !is_home() && !is_front_page() || is_paged() ) {

echo '<ul id="crumbs">';

global $post;
$home = get_bloginfo('url');
echo '<li><a href="' . $home . '">' . $name . '</a></li> ' . $delimiter . ' ';

if ( is_category() ) {
  global $wp_query;
  $cat_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
  $thisCat = $cat_obj->term_id;
  $thisCat = get_category($thisCat);
  $parentCat = get_category($thisCat->parent);
  if ($thisCat->parent != 0) echo '<li>' .(get_category_parents($parentCat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ')) ;
  echo $currentBefore ;
  echo single_cat_title();
  echo $currentAfter;

} elseif ( is_day() ) {
  echo '<li><a href="' . get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')) . '">' . get_the_time('Y') . '</a></li> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
  echo '<li><a href="' . get_month_link(get_the_time('Y'),get_the_time('m')) . '">' . get_the_time('F') . '</a></li> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
  echo $currentBefore . get_the_time('d') . $currentAfter;

} elseif ( is_month() ) {
  echo '<a href="' . get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')) . '">' . get_the_time('Y') . '</a></li> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
  echo $currentBefore . get_the_time('F') . $currentAfter;

} elseif ( is_year() ) {
  echo $currentBefore . get_the_time('Y') . $currentAfter;

} elseif ( is_single() ) {
  $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0];
  echo '<li>' .get_category_parents($cat, FALSE, ' <li>' . $delimiter . '');
  the_title();
  echo $currentAfter;

} elseif ( is_page() && !$post->post_parent ) {
  echo $currentBefore;
  the_title();
  echo $currentAfter;

} elseif ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {
  $parent_id  = $post->post_parent;
  $breadcrumbs = array();
  while ($parent_id) {
    $page = get_page($parent_id);
    $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . get_the_title($page->ID) . '</a>';
    $parent_id  = $page->post_parent;
  }
  $breadcrumbs = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
  foreach ($breadcrumbs as $crumb) echo $crumb . ' ' . $delimiter . ' ';
  echo $currentBefore;
  the_title();
  echo $currentAfter;

} elseif ( is_search() ) {
  echo $currentBefore . 'Search results for &#39;' . get_search_query() . '&#39;' . $currentAfter;

} elseif ( is_tag() ) {
  echo $currentBefore . 'Posts tagged &#39;';
  single_tag_title();
  echo '&#39;' . $currentAfter;

} elseif ( is_author() ) {
   global $author;
  $userdata = get_userdata($author);
  echo $currentBefore . 'Articles posted by ' . $userdata->display_name . $currentAfter;

} elseif ( is_404() ) {
  echo $currentBefore . 'Error 404' . $currentAfter;
}

if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
  if ( is_category() || is_day() || is_month() || is_year() || is_search() || is_tag() || is_author() ) echo ' (';
  echo __('Page') . ' ' . get_query_var('paged');
  if ( is_category() || is_day() || is_month() || is_year() || is_search() || is_tag() || is_author() ) echo ')';
}

   echo '</ul>';

   }
  }
```

To call it just put in

```
   <?php if (function_exists('wordpress_breadcrumbs')) wordpress_breadcrumbs(); ?>
```